# Using jQuery $(this) to select anything in this form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, this

have multiple forms on one page but all with the same class name.

I want to make it so that if there is no content in the text area, the submit button is disabled.

This works as you can see here i have done that:

http://jsfiddle.net/WJnqw/

However, this obviously will affect all of the forms with the same submit button classname.

I have tried changing the code to include e.g:

```
$(this).find(".addcommentbutton").prop("disabled", true);
```

As i thought that would select the form, and find the add comment button.

But it doesnt work.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: **Note:** IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` was the window. You need to pass the context somehow.

Here's a working version that shows two ways of either specifying what `this` in the function refers to or letting jquery do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/LVf5w/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.addpostcomment').each(function() {
        disableComments.call(this); // specify what "this" will be in the function
    });
    $(".addpostcomment").keyup(disableComments); //let jquery specify that "this" will be the element
});

function disableComments() {
    $(this).closest('form').find(".addcommentbutton").prop("disabled", $(this).val().length < 1);
};
```

You could also just do this instead of iterating and calling the function:

http://jsfiddle.net/LX2Dj/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".addpostcomment").keyup(disableComments).trigger('keyup');
});
```

Or (my preference) do away with the anonymous function altogether:

http://jsfiddle.net/sfuHU/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".addpostcomment").keyup(function() {
        $(this).closest('form').find(".addcommentbutton").prop("disabled", $(this).val().length < 1);   
    }).trigger('keyup');
});
```

Note that you have duplicate `id`s on your elements. The `id` must be unique.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the much simpler way around this too! I didnt intend on having multiple forms of this id on the same page. Will remove the id and its not needed and stick with the classes

Answer (score 0):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WJnqw/1/)***

You need to use `.next()` not find & also use `this` directly in the `keyup` event

`$(this).next('.addcommentbutton').prop('disabled', !($(this).val().length > 0));`

```
// comment form not allow submit when empty
    $(document).ready(function () {
        disableComments();
        $( ".addpostcomment" ).keyup(function() {
            $(this).next('.addcommentbutton').prop('disabled', !($(this).val().length > 0));
        });
    });

    function disableComments() {
        var commentLength = $('.addpostcomment').val().length;
        if (commentLength < 1) {
            $(".addcommentbutton").prop("disabled", true);  
        } else {
            $(".addcommentbutton").prop("disabled", false); 
        }
    };
```